# Where does the girlfriend work?

Tags: plot-explanation, man-of-tai-chi

In [Man of Tai Chi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2016940/), where exactly does Tiger's girlfriend work? I'm guessing that it's some kind of a government office possibly dealing with "historical preservation". But do we know what department or organisation it is for sure?

Also, does Keanu actually lay a foundation for this before/when Tiger is first shown meeting the girl while making a delivery?